# YTT: append array items together but remove duplicates

Tags: yaml, ytt

I have two documents:

```
---
resources:
  - index: 1
  - index: 2
```

and

```
resources:
  - index: 2
  - index: 3
  - index: 4
```

My desired output is:

```
resources:
  - index: 1
  - index: 2
  - index: 3
  - index: 4
```

I tried

```
#@ load("@ytt:overlay", "overlay")
#@ load("@ytt:data", "data")

#@overlay/match by=overlay.all, expects="1+"
---
resources:
  #@overlay/match by=lambda idx,left,right: data.values.left[idx]==data.values.right[idx], missing_ok=True
  #@overlay/replace
  - index: 1
  - index: 2
```

```
#@ load("@ytt:overlay", "overlay")
#@ load("@ytt:data", "data")

#@overlay/match by=overlay.all, expects="1+"
---
resources: 
  #@overlay/match by=lambda idx,left,right: data.values.left[idx]==data.values.right[idx], missing_ok=True
  #@overlay/replace
  - index: 2
  - index: 3
  - index: 3
```

This does not work.
How do I use the array values to make ytt match by logic?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, this looks like a job for the built-in overlay key matcher.

Turn your second document into an overlay that will be applied on the first document. That first document will be a plain YAML document.

```
#@ load("@ytt:overlay", "overlay")

#@overlay/match by=overlay.all
---
#@overlay/match-child-defaults missing_ok=True
resources:
  #@overlay/match by="index"
  - index: 2
    more: True
  #@overlay/match by="index"
  - index: 3
  #@overlay/match by="index"
  - index: 4
```

[ytt Playground](https://carvel.dev/ytt/#gist:https://gist.github.com/jtigger/81639ea1618adb3b783ce66d4ecae523)

Where:

- out-of-the-box, `ytt`'s `@overlay/match by=` when given a string value, will assume you're naming the key on which to match (here, `index`) ([docs](https://carvel.dev/ytt/docs/v0.44.0/lang-ref-ytt-overlay/#overlaymatch)).
- within an Overlay, each array item is its own edit. In an Overlay, the default action on an array item is `@overlay/append`. If you want a different action (e.g. you want to merge), then you need to specify that *for each array item*. That's why there's an `@overlay/match by="index"` on *each* array item in the solution.
- when applying an Overlay, `ytt` for each key, will look for that same key in the target document. If it doesn't find that key, that's an error. You can let `ytt` know that you want new keys to be added by including the `missing_ok=True` attribute.

  - this gets verbose quickly, adding this to every node in the overlay. There's a short-hand annotation that lets you set it once at the top of a tree of nodes: [`@overlay/match-child-defaults`](https://carvel.dev/ytt/docs/v0.44.0/lang-ref-ytt-overlay/#overlaymatch-child-defaults).

    Here, I've annotated `resources:` that way. This means that *the children* of `resources:` all have the `missing_ok=True` attribute: new keys will be added.